# Deploy NativeScript Project to Web Browser?

Tags: nativescript

Is it possible to deploy a NativeScript project to run inside a web browser? and upload to a public server.

**For example -**

```
tns run web
```

`<Platform>` is the target mobile platform for which you want to run your project. You can set the following target platforms:

```
* android - Run your project on all Android devices and emulators.
* ios - Run your project on all iOS devices and simulators.
```

I found **ng serve** but looks to be NativeScript Angular based.

I am developing for {N} Javascript Core (not TypeScript or Angular).

Answer (score 1):

From what I have found as of - "June 2019" it is not supported. Please post any findings and I'll accept your answer.